# Voltage shifter 0-30VDC

Tags: arduino, level-shifting

I am required to generate and measure squared signal (PWM like). I should cover a 0-30VDC amplitude. High level of the signal is 30 VDC, low level is 0VDC. The bandwith to be covered is 0-20kHz. I should use Arduino to generate and measure these signals.

I thought that the more convenient way to achieve these operations would be a kind of "logic level shifter", but I cannot find a suitable component for my application. I would like to bring the 30V back to 3.3V and vice-versa so that the Arduino can both generate and measure the signals.

To circumvent the issue, I thought about transistors, comparators, voltage divider, amplificators,... but I am unsure about what to choose (COTS if possible) and think a bidirectionnal voltage level shifter would be the best solution since it would cover both the need to generate and the need to measure.

Any idea to address this issue ? It would be better if the component would be on the shell, but if a design from scratch should be done, it may be OK too.

Comment: Look for "half bridge driver" instead of a level shifter to generate the 0-30VDC signal and use a resistor divider to measure it back. If you designed a circuit using that, we're happy to give feedback on it.

Comment: Describe the application itself. Context matters a lot. You've said far to little about the circumstances and goals and instead abstracted the situation until it is very difficult to be of much help.

Comment: @jonk That's what I said in the first paragraph. I should generate and measure frequencies of control signals with a arduino board. However, the voltage level are 0-30VDC. The arduino board (like any other microcontroller) cannot work in that frequency span. I would like to find a way to adapt that "30VDC logic" to a 3.3 one. This is a part of a system which will run automatic tests on some hardware.

Comment: @Huisman Yes, I had thought to voltage divider, but not to Half bridge driver. But still 2 components, not a real "voltage shift". In that case, why not chosing directly some MOS transistor ?

Comment: "automatic tests on some hardware" is abstract  generating 30 V until easy. Monitoring it is easy. But details about the closed loop matter, I think. It isn't interesting just yet, to me. Maybe someone else.

Comment: You shift down the high level (30V) to a low level (3.3V) which an Arduino can measure.  Resistor divider is the easiest way with least components to "shift" down a voltage level. Using mosfets will involve resistors as well, so more components. Please explain why it is not a real "voltage shift". (BTW, I would call it a *(voltage) level* shift. I would interpret a voltage shift as an signal originally ranging between 0V..30V becomes a signal between 25V...55V)

Comment: Do you want to have a variable DC voltage source or a PWM waveform with the variable frequency & variable peak voltage? what is the current sourcing ability of the DC source?

Comment: @Huisman you're right, I mistook. I was more thinking to specialized component for logic level switching which are often called "voltage level shifter". For now I am considering the voltage divider for first prototyping

Comment: @yogece No, I should have a constant 30V DC voltage which should be able to deliver up to around a hunderd mA I think. Signal are just command signal so they shouldn't drive much current.

Comment: @frankee i got it. you could use an analog switch such as MAX4649 which is usable upto 1MHZ Vcc upto 36V signal handling is close to rail

Answer (score 0):

This may suffice

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNxrei.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your design, I was exactly thinking to a home-made solution.